# Is it possible to see who disabled a SQL backup job?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql

I'm looking to see if it's possible to audit who disabled a SQL backup job in Microsoft SQL 2008's SSMS on Windows Server 2008 R2. We have a couple admins and I'm attempting to pin point who disabled these jobs. Looking through logs, I can see when they logged into the Server but not who disabled the jobs.

Comment: Have you asked them?

Comment: Yes and as if it were an 80's sitcom, they pointed fingers at each other.

Comment: From what I'm reading it doesn't look like this is possible as SQL Server doesn't keep this type of metadata in any system tables, etc. You'd have to look over trace files, audit records if applicable, and potentially event viewer logs. see some answers here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/425f2ec2-5faa-4a65-8c6d-9dda3bd6cc77/who-disabled-sql-job?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Comment: Additionally as a workaround you could try setting up another SQL Agent job or something that checks to see is a job value is set to disable (zero) and if so then run `EXEC msdb..sp_update_job) @job_name = '<jobname>', @enabled = 1` to set it to enabled. Just a quick thought but potentially doing it from sp_start_job with SQLCMD or something. Lastly look over this article for creating a trigger when something like this may occur... It's from 2009 though so not sure what version of SQL Server it'll run on... something easy to test perhaps... Quick thoughts